# Converting radians to parsecs in the parallax formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help figuring out how this conversion from radians to parsecs works in the parallax formula. Here is the initial formula:

1. $d = \dfrac{1 AU}{tan (p)} ≃ \dfrac{1 AU}{p}$

Then, we need to convert radians rad to parsecs " where:

$1 rad = 57.2967795^{\circ} = 206264.806"$

2. $d ≃ \dfrac{206,265}{p"}AU$

The text book just jumps from the first to second formula probably because the conversion is very elementary. However, I've looked at multiple websites and articles explaining the same conversion for some days now but still can't understand how the conversion is made. In my head, when converting from rad to parsecs, it should only affect the denominator like so:

$d ≃ \dfrac{AU}{206,265p"}$

Can someone help explain to me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the symbol $p$ representing two very different things, which is confusing.

At the expense of using a lot of words instead of one little symbol, we can write the original formula like this:

$$ d \approx \frac{1\ \mathrm{AU}}{\text{number of radians of parallax}}. $$

Now if you have $p$ arc seconds of parallax, how many radians is that?

As you showed in the question, a radian is much larger than an arc second.
Therefore an arc second is much smaller than a radian.
If you have $p$ arc seconds, you surely have much **less** than $p$ radians,
not $206265p$ radians.

So just to be clear, the point of formula number $2$ in the question is that you are given a parallax measured in seconds of arc, specifically, the parallax is $p$ seconds of arc. And you have a simple formula for the distance in parsecs if you know the parallax in radians. So in fact you need to convert seconds of arc (given) into radians in order to make use of the first formula. The idea of the second formula is just that we plug the converted angle into the first formula so that you have the entire calculation in one formula.

You have $1\ \mathrm{rad} \approx 206265''.$
Therefore $1'' \approx \frac{1}{206265}\ \mathrm{rad}.$
Therefore $p'' \approx \frac{1}{206265}p\ \mathrm{rad}.$
Therefore if you have $p$ arc seconds of parallax,

$$ d \approx \frac{1\ \mathrm{AU}}{\frac{1}{206265}p}
 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{206265}p}\ \mathrm{AU}. $$

But we can simplify this by multiplying both numerator and denominator by $206265$:

$$ d \approx \frac{206265}p\ \mathrm{AU}. $$

If you need the symbol $''$ to remind you that $p$ was measured in seconds of arc, I would write it like this so that it cancels out correctly:

$$ d \approx \frac{206265''}{p''}\ \mathrm{AU}. $$